# Perdendo dados do arquivo de Designer.cs ao abrir formulário - C# Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, winforms, desserialização

Tenho um Editor customizado que adiciona botões em uma coleção. Esse procedimento está funcionando bem, os dados são serializados no arquivo de Designer mas quando reabro o formulário ou faço um build do projeto, os dados que estavam no Designer desaparecem.

O que antes no arquivo de Designer estava serializado como:

```
// 
// MyForm
// 
this.buttons.Add(this.button1);
this.buttons.Add(this.button2);
this.buttons.Add(this.button3);
```

O trecho de código auto gerado acima desaparece na reabertura do formulário ou quando faço o build do projeto:

```
// 
// myForm
//
```

*Obs.: Apenas a variável que tenho o editor customizado.*

Pelo que me parece, isto parece um problema de deserialização. Já tentei criar meu próprio serializador (sem sucesso), mas talvez possa haver uma solução mais simples.

Comment: Cara, não entendi o que "desserialização" tem a ver com isso. O problema parece ser que o VS reescreve o código do `.Designer` em determinados momentos.

Comment: Os dados de um objeto são serializados no arquivo de designer para guardar o "estado visual" desse objeto. Quando o formulário é reaberto, há uma desserialização para reconstruir o objeto/controle, certo?! Me parece que na reconstrução do controle ele pode não encontrar como recontruir esse controle (por ser customizado) **ou** o trecho de código antes presente no Designer agora não é encontrado. Mas é claro, que ainda posso estar errado, vim buscar ajuda :)